# Autofocus Gravity Form Field

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, autofocus

Trying to get a cursor to appear in one field in my Gravity Form. This is my Javascript, but it's not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { jQuery('#input_22_1').focus(); });
</script>
```

I've double checked the input several times to make sure I had the correct one yet this isn't working. The page I'm trying to get it working on is here: http://tinyurl.com/h8muwvp and the field is the Name of Business field.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your Javascript. From the console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

`custom_js.js:7`

A more elegant solution would be to use the [HTML `autofocus` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) on the form field.

Comment: A note that while the autofocus attribute is certainly a more elegant solution, it is not currently supported by gravity forms (That is, there is no good way through the UI to add it) - so you are likely to need to go ahead with a solution like yours (after you fix the error in `custom_js.js` preventing the rest of your scripts from executing). One way to make it (slightly) more elegant is to use a class - so you can add the class autofocus to that field in the form editor and target it like `$('.autofocus input').focus()`. That way your code is not beholden to the auto generated field ID.